# Question about the function field of a noetherian, integral, locally factorial scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. Assume $X$ is noetherian, integral, and locally factorial. 
Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $X$, then the function field of $X$ is $K(X):=O_{X, \eta}$. 
Let $Y$ be a prime divisor of $Y$, and $y$ its generic point.

I am trying to show that $K(X)$ is isomorphic to $Frac(O_{X,y})$. 
I would appreciate if someone could explain me how to construct the isomorphism. Thank you.

Below is my attempt at this when $X = \operatorname{Spec}R$. In this case the generic point is the zero ideal. Let $Y$ be a prime divisor, say it is $Y = V(P)$ where $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, in other words this is the generic point of $Y$. Then
$$
O_{X, P} = R_P
$$ 
and since we know that this is an integral domain because $R$ is. 
Then it follows that 
$$
Frac(R_P) \cong  Frac{R} = R_{(0)}
$$
where the isomorphism is given by
$$
\frac{r/x}{r'/y} \mapsto \frac{r y}{r'x}. 
$$

This establishes the case when $X$ is affine. What am I not seeing is how can we reduce to this case when it $X$ is not affine. Can we always find an affine open that contains $\eta$ and $y$?

Comment: Can you do this in the case that $X$ is affine?

Comment: explanation even for the affine case would be appreciated... thank you

Comment: I'd be happy to explain in full after you demonstrate your efforts. Until then, I'll give you the following hint. Suppose we work in the affine case, that is, $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$. What do you know about the ring $R$? Can you write down $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$ in terms of $R$? What is it? What is it's fraction field?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I managed to do the affine case. But I am still not sure how to deal with the general case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic point $\eta$ is, more or less by definition, dense in $X$. So given any affine open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ in $X$, you also get $\eta \in U$ for free.

After that, since you have $\eta, y \in U$, the affine case applies.